# Is it possible to knock over a bowling pin without hitting it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, everyday-life, aerodynamics

I bowl professionally and there is a saying when you barely hit a pin and it barely falls over. People say that you "hit it with the wind." I've been thinking, is it actually possible to knock over a bowling pin without hitting it? How fast would you have to roll the ball to where the air force around the ball is enough to knock over the pin? All I can do to help is say that the average bowling pin weighs about 3 pounds 6 ounces, and that (while the world record for fastest bowling ball is 100 mph) the average bowler rolls it around 16-21 mph.

Comment: I think this problem is better tackled with experimentation than by calculations from first principles. Aerodynamics is notoriously hard to work out on paper.

Comment: The first thing I would look at is how much energy you need to give to a pin to knock it over. You should be able to get this from the geometry: how far does the pin have to tip before it will fall (i.e. at what angle does its center of mass go outside the footprint of the base)? Then find out the increase in height of the center of mass at this critical angle and multiply by the pin mass and $g$ to get the energy that would need to be delivered to knock it over. Then you gotta think about how much energy the "wind" can deliver to the pin.

Comment: I'd like to see someone roll a bowling ball at 100 mph.  That's the speed of an elite baseball pitcher's fastball.